# How can I hide the node boundary in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I am drawing a graph with graphviz. Even though I have `penwidth=0` for the nodes, I still see the node boundary. How do I get rid of the node boundary?

My annotation in dot is something like this:

```
strict graph  {
    graph [bgcolor=white];
    0    [fillcolor=red,
        style=filled,
        shape=octagon,
        penwidht=0,
        fontsize=10,
        fixedsize=True,
        width=0.5,
        height=0.5,
        type=3];
    2    [shape=octagon,
        style=filled,
        fillcolor=gray,
        penwidth=0];
    0 -- 2  [penwidth=0.5,
        color=gray];
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me:

```
node [shape=plaintext]
```

Source: https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/tools/Graphviz/examples/index

Comment: this doesn't work if you want to use a shape like circle

Answer (score 6):

The issue is you have a typo.

`penwidht` should be `penwidth`

```
strict graph  {
    graph [bgcolor=white];
    0    [fillcolor=red,
        style=filled,
        shape=octagon,
        penwidth=0,
        fontsize=10,
        fixedsize=True,
        width=0.5,
        height=0.5,
        type=3];
    2    [shape=octagon,
        style=filled,
        fillcolor=gray,
        penwidth=0];
    0 -- 2  [penwidth=0.5,
        color=gray];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

setlinewidth works for me:

```
strict graph  {
    graph [bgcolor=white];
    0    [fillcolor=red,
        style="filled,setlinewidth(0)",
        shape=octagon,
    penwidht=0,
        fontsize=10,
        fixedsize=True,
        width=0.5,
        height=0.5,
        type=3];
    2    [shape=octagon,
        style=filled,
        fillcolor=gray,
        penwidth=0];
    0 -- 2  [penwidth=0.5,
        color=gray];
}
```